# Konva How to display images from array

Tags: konvajs

can you please help me?
i am trying to display png Images from an PHP array (with x y psoition preset) into the container/canvas. But have not found any sample showing that. All images appear on the same position. Then I want the pngs to be dragged and dropped some whre else in the canvas.

Your input is very much appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the problem correctly.

```js
<?php foreach($images as $image) : ?>

var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
  var image = new Konva.Image({
    x: <?php echo $image->x ?>,
    y: <?php echo $image->y ?>,
    image: imageObj,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  });
};

imageObj.src = <?php echo $image->source ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Minan, but somehow I miss the draw part. Do not knwo exactly where and how to put it correctly.

Comment: First you need to create a stage. You also need a layer to add to this stage. You can then add the images into it. Examples may not be exactly what you want, but if you examine it a bit, you may find the answer. Try and don't forget to write here if you get an error.
https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Drop_DOM_Element.html
https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Planets_Image_Map.html